# Asking two different people in a same question

Tags: conversations

I'm wondering which one is correct to ask two people for coffee. As example;

1. 山田さん、佐藤さん、コーヒーを　のみますか。
2. 山田さんと佐藤さんは、コーヒー　のみますか。

Comment: Is it intentional that the second phrase doesn't have the を particle?

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences are not the same.

The first sentence could definitely be a question of Yamada-san and Sato-san.  "Yamada-san!  Sato-san!  Will you have some coffee".  (Exclamation point is used only to emphasize that you're directly addressing them in the first sentence.)

The second sentence (ignoring that you left out the object marker を) is a question:  "Are both Yamada-san and Sato-san going to drink coffee?"  (Notice, you're not directly addressing either Yamada or Sato in the second sentence.  You talking *about* them.)

Generally, in this sort of situation though, you would ask more indirectly

> 山田さん、佐藤さん、コーヒーは　のみませんか